# PHP Select has no options

Tags: php

What is wrong in this script, because only the `<select>` box appears, but it does not have any `<option>`'s. The select-box is just empty.

And here is the script:

```
$titleBlock->addCell(
'<select id="my-select" class="text" name="task_owner">
       <?php 
            foreach ($user_list as $key=>$value){
                echo <option style="color:'.$new[$key].'" value="'.$key.'">'.$value.'</option>;
            }
        ?> 
 </select>');
```

Answered:

```
$option_str = '';
foreach ($user_list as $key=>$value){
    $option_str .= '<option style="color:'.$new[$key].'" value="'.$key.'">'.$value.'</option>';
}

  $titleBlock->addCell(
        '<select id="my-select" class="text" name="task_owner">
        "'.$option_str.'"
        </select>');
```

Comment: Hint: Have a look at the HTML code that is generated by your PHP script. ;)

Comment: I assume that this is using a framework of some kind; you might want to tag this with the name of the framework, too.

Comment: You need to tell us what you have found so far. You showed us a few variables like `$user_list` and `$new`. What are their values?

Comment: Topic is answered, thnx for reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try as :

```
$option_str = '';
foreach ($user_list as $key=>$value){
    $option_str .= '<option style="color:'.$new[$key].'" value="'.$key.'">'.$value.'</option>';
}

  $titleBlock->addCell(
        '<select id="my-select" class="text" name="task_owner">
        "'.$option_str.'"
        </select>');
```

Answer (score 1):

The option gererating code is not getting executed in that location.

Try this

```
<?php 
    $options= '';
    foreach ($user_list as $key=>$value){
        $options.=  '<option style="color:'.$new[$key].'" value="'.$key.'">'.$value.'</option>';
    }

$titleBlock
  ->addCell('<select id="my-select" class="text" name="task_owner"> .
            $options.
           '</select>'
            );
```